# Why Graphical effects doesn't change in PyQt5?

Tags: python-3.x, qt5, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 and Python3 to write a program.
I am using QGraphicsBlurEffect to make a blur effect on the main widget when a pop up windows is shown.
The problem is that when the popup window is closed the blur effect is still on the main widget and it doesn't show as normal. How can I set it to normal after closing the popup window?(I set the graphicsEffect of mainwindow to None in closing event of popup window but it doesn't change anything).

This is the code:

main widget:

```
    self.blureffect = QGraphicsBlurEffect(self) #defining the effect

    def fontpgshow(self): #shows the popup window
        self.setGraphicsEffect(self.blureffect) #puts the blur effect on the main widget

        #the 3 bottom lines show the popup window
        import fontwindow
        self.fontpg = fontwindow.fontpage()
        self.fontpg.show()
```

popup window:

```
    def closeEvent(self,event):
        event.accept()
        #in the bottom lines I set the effect of main window to None
        import settingswindow
        self.setpg = settingswindow.settingspage()
        self.setpg.setGraphicsEffect(None)
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: @eyllanesc there are a lot of codes i can't really put all of them here. You can see my question like this: " What is the correct way of using QGraphicsBlurEffect in PyQt?

Comment: Are you sure `self.setpg` refers to the correct `QWidget` -- what does `self.setpg.graphicsEffect()` return?  Otherwise, there's nothing obviously wrong with the code shown.

Comment: @G.M. yes it refers to the 'settingspage' and that is a QWidget that it acts like my setting page in the software. Before setting graphics effect it returns None and after that it returns `<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect object at 0x036B3DF0> .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by changing the type of the pop up window from `QWidget` to `QDialog` and I used `self.accept()` and `self.reject()` in the `QDialog` for sending signals back to the main widget that here it was the setting page. After getting signal I set the graphics effect of the main widget to `None` and everything is working ok now.